# Devise: Authentication after Registration without Confirmable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, user-registration, devise-confirmable

**Use case**: User fills out a form to add a product and register at once. When the user has submitted the combined form, the app authenticates the user and is logged in (assume validations passed) without the need to confirm or login.

I've removed the confirmable feature out, but when the user fill out the form, it succeeds, but the user doesn't get logged in unless they go to a login form. This isn't such a great experience, so is there a way to Register a user and immediately log them in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I actually wanted was [sign_in(@user)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Sign-in-from-a-controller) from my controller

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login without confirmation then Remove **:confirmable** option from devise options in User model.

Comment: That wouldn't help for this case. I had already removed confirmable, but it wouldn't keep them signed in after my custom registration.